# sizeof single struct member in C

Tags: c, struct, sizeof

I am trying to declare a struct that is dependent upon another struct.
I want to use `sizeof` to be safe/pedantic.

```
typedef struct _parent
{
  float calc ;
  char text[255] ;
  int used ;
} parent_t ;
```

Now I want to declare a struct `child_t` that has the same size as `parent_t.text`.

How can I do this?  (Pseudo-code below.)

```
typedef struct _child
{
  char flag ;
  char text[sizeof(parent_t.text)] ;
  int used ;
} child_t ;
```

I tried a few different ways with `parent_t` and `struct _parent`, but my compiler will not accept.

As a trick, this seems to work:

```
parent_t* dummy ;
typedef struct _child
{
  char flag ;
  char text[sizeof(dummy->text)] ;
  int used ;
} child_t ;
```

Is it possible to declare `child_t` without the use of `dummy`?

Answer (score 257, accepted):

Although defining the buffer size with a `#define` is one idiomatic way to do it, another would be to use a macro like this:

```
#define member_size(type, member) (sizeof( ((type *)0)->member ))
```

and use it like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    float calc;
    char text[255];
    int used;
} Parent;

typedef struct
{
    char flag;
    char text[member_size(Parent, text)];
    int used;
} Child;
```

I'm actually a bit surprised that `sizeof(((type *)0)->member)` is even allowed as a constant expression.  Cool stuff.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know sizeof((type *)0)->member) works. Am not on my dev machine now, but does this work for all the compilers? Thanks for that Joey.

Comment: @Gangadhar:  Yes, this works for all compilers.  The operand of `sizeof` is not evaluated, so there is no issue with dereferencing the null pointer (because it isn't actually dereferenced).

Comment: wonderful? its plain C89, see implementation of "offsetof" in <stddef.h> or the same implementation http://www.eetimes.com/design/other/4024941/Learn-a-new-trick-with-the-offsetof--macro

Comment: Hi can anyone explain this sizeof(((type *)0)->member. I am not able to make sense of it :(

Comment: @XavierGeoffrey: Here, sizeof infers the type of ((type *)0)->member, and returns the size of that type.  ((type *)0) is just a null pointer of the struct type.  ptr->member is (at compile time) an expression whose type is that of the member.  The code within the sizeof never runs (if it did, the program would segfault!).  Only the type of value within the sizeof is looked at.

Comment: The [Wikipedia page for offset_of](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offsetof) notes this as undefined behaviour according to the C standard, so I wouldn't bet on it working with all compilers.

Comment: The protective parens seem to be slightly misplaced.  You want `(sizeof ((type *)0)->member)`.

Comment: @TobySpeight Thanks, I updated my answer to include outer parens.  But I kept the parens after sizeof since it's not obvious that `->` binds tighter than `sizeof`.

Answer (score 47):

I am not on my development machine right now, but I think you can do one of the following:

```
sizeof(((parent_t *)0)->text)

sizeof(((parent_t){0}).text)
```

---

**Edit**: I like the member_size macro Joey suggested using this technique, I think I would use that.

Comment: The second form is very nice (and conceptually clean in that it does not involve null pointers), but you should mention that it's not possible in pre-C99 compilers.

Comment: if the struct is very large and memory is a constraint first one should be preferred.
someone correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @PunyCode - the `sizeof` operand is evaluated at compile time, so no memory issue.

Comment: @PunyCode The first one should **never** be preferred - it's dereferncing a `NULL` pointer and is undefined behavior.  "But it works!" or anything like "But that's how `offsetof()` is defined!" is a response from someone who does not understand undefined behavior.  *Implementations* themselves are not subject to the C standard - but **your** code is.

Answer (score 16):

You are free to use `FIELD_SIZEOF(t, f)` in the Linux kernel.
It's just defined as following:

```
#define FIELD_SIZEOF(t, f) (sizeof(((t*)0)->f))
```

This type of macro is mentioned in other answers. But it's more portable to use an already-defined macro.

Comment: FIELD_SIZEOF is the macro used in modern Linux kernels, found in linux/kernel.h

Comment: @ColinIanKing So this is an idiomatic way in C in general to get the struct member size? Isn't such a macro included in a Standard in modern C yet?

Comment: To my knowledge there is no equivalent macro in standard C.

Comment: It was recently [removed](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/1f07dcc459d5f2c639f185f6e94829a0c79f2b4c) from linux/kernel.h.

Comment: @AndriyMakukha I ran into this as well… it’s now called `sizeof_field` (`<linux/stddef.h>`) with no net change, just a rename.

Answer (score 11):

Use a preprocessor directive, i.e. #define:

```
#define TEXT_LEN 255

typedef struct _parent
{
  float calc ;
  char text[TEXT_LEN] ;
  int used ;
} parent_t ;

typedef struct _child
{
  char flag ;
  char text[TEXT_LEN] ;
  int used ;
} child_t ;
```

Comment: Agree with Nyan. The other solutions work, but don't accomplish anything different. If you want to be more explicit, call it PARENT_TEXT_LEN or something equally descriptive. You can then also use it in conditionals throughout your code to prevent buffer length errors and it will be doing simple integer comparisons.

Comment: i think the advantage of the sizeof solution is that you don't need access to the parent struct, if it is defined in a library or somewhere else.

Comment: @evilclown: but you do: "char text[member_size(Parent, text)];" You need to reference the "Parent".

Comment: i don't think you understood me.  suppose the parent struct is `drand48_data` (defined in stdlib.h) and you want the sizeof `__x`.  you cannot `#define X_LEN 3` and change the stdlib.h, using `member_size` is superior when you don't have access to the source of the parent struct, which seems like a reasonable situation.

Comment: This solution is not applicable if the parent_t structure comes from some library, where you are not allowed (or don't want) to change the declarations of the structure members.

Answer (score 6):

`struct.h` has them already defined,

```
#define fldsiz(name, field) \
    (sizeof(((struct name *)0)->field))
```

so you could,

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* EXIT_SUCCESS */
#include <stdio.h>  /* printf */
#include <struct.h> /* fldsiz */

struct Penguin {
    char name[128];
    struct Penguin *child[16];
};
static const int name_size  = fldsiz(Penguin, name) / sizeof(char);
static const int child_size = fldsiz(Penguin, child) / sizeof(struct Penguin *);

int main(void) {
    printf("Penguin.name is %d chars and Penguin.child is %d Penguin *.\n",
           name_size, child_size);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

but, on looking in the header, it appears that this is a BSD thing and not ANSI or POSIX standard. I tried it on a Linux machine and it didn't work; limited usefulness.

Comment: TIL, and I’m a BSD person… that being said, `<struct.h>` has been removed from OpenBSD at least (“unused and should not be used”).

Answer (score 5):

You can use a preprocessor directive for size as:

```
#define TEXT_MAX_SIZE 255
```

and use it in both parent and child.

Comment: yep, but it's not always an option: say, in linux `/usr/include/bits/dirent.h` the size of the `d_name` field (struct `direct` / `dirent`) is not defined as `DIRSIZ` any more but hard-coded; so `sizeof()` seems to be the only clean way to keep the dependency

Answer (score 5):

### c++ solution:

sizeof(Type::member) seems to be working as well:

```
struct Parent
{
    float calc;
    char text[255];
    int used;
};

struct Child
{
    char flag;
    char text[sizeof(Parent::text)];
    int used;
};
```

Comment: The question is about C, not C++.

Comment: it also fails for `sizeof(struct Parent::text)` and therefore cannot be put into a macro

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility would be to define a type. The fact that you want to ensure the same size for the two fields is an indicator that you have the same semantics for them, I think.

```
typedef char description[255];
```

and then have a field

```
description text;
```

in both of your types.

Answer (score 0):

@joey-adams, thank you!
I was searching the same thing, but for non char array and it works perfectly fine even this way:

```
#define member_dim(type, member) sizeof(((type*)0)->member) / \
                                 sizeof(((type*)0)->member[0])

struct parent {
        int array[20];
};

struct child {
        int array[member_dim(struct parent, array)];
};

int main ( void ) {
        return member_dim(struct child, array);
}
```

It returns 20 as expected.

And, @brandon-horsley, this works good too:

```
#define member_dim(type, member) sizeof(((type){0}).member) / \
                                 sizeof(((type){0}).member[0])
```