# sizeof a struct member

Tags: c, sizeof

How can I get the size of a member in a struct in C?

```
struct A
{
        char arr[64];
};
```

i need something like that:

sizeof(A::arr)

thanks

Comment: What happened when you tried `sizeof(A::arr)`?

Comment: C said "syntax error" in response to 'sizeof(A::arr)'.  C does not use a double colon anywhere in its syntax.

Comment: @pmg: I don't think that `::` has been introduced to C, yet.

Comment: Here is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553296/c-sizeof-single-struct-member

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
sizeof(((struct A*)0)->arr);
```

Briefly, cast a null pointer to a type of `struct A*`, but since the operand of `sizeof` is not evaluated, this is legal and allows you to get size of struct members without creating an instance of the struct.

Basically, we are pretending that an instance of it exists at address 0 and can be used for offset and `sizeof` determination.

To further elaborate, read this article:

http://www.embedded.com/design/prototyping-and-development/4024941/Learn-a-new-trick-with-the-offsetof--macro

Comment: There are macros for this construct in Windows (`RTL_FIELD_SIZE(type, field)` and Linux (`FIELD_SIZE(t,f)`).

Comment: @Michael: There's no reason to use non-portable system-specific macros when you can write your own portable implementation just as easily.

Comment: /*Huh, interestingly enough this does not work with abstract  structs/classes*/  It does not work on static constants within the same class.

Comment: @RamonZarazuaB. in C++ you should be using `sizeof(A::arr)`

Comment: This answer seems very portable. I tested on Linux, macos, and FreeBSD (implementation via macro at [commit 5e93355](https://github.com/theimpossibleastronaut/rmw/pull/352/commits/5e93355bcd8a1cd3fd8ff8970b0600c213aaf1ee)). Thanks.