# Sizeof Struct Member at Compile Time Trick Not Working

Tags: c

Found this answer here:
[sizeof a struct member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864583/sizeof-a-struct-member)

Copied it completely into my code, but my compiler objects that I have a pointer to an incomplete class type.

```
uint8_t clStructCount = sizeof(((struct ALMConfStr *) 0)->IntelRecsPerPg);
```

What am I doing wrong? I want to set clStructCount equal to the value of IntelRecsPerPg at runtime; I thought this was the trick to do so.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the definition of `struct ALMConfStr` visible at this point in the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of your structure needs to be *visible* at the point where the compiler encounters your sizeof code.

So, this translation unit should work:

```
struct ALMConfStr {
  int IntelRecsPerPg[MagicNumber];
};
// ...
uint8_t clStructCount = sizeof(((struct ALMConfStr *) 0)->IntelRecsPerPg);
```

whether it's all in one file, or the struct is in a header `#include`d before your `sizeof` code.

However, this:

```
struct ALMConfStr;
// ...
uint8_t clStructCount = sizeof(((struct ALMConfStr *) 0)->IntelRecsPerPg);
```

won't work, because the compiler doesn't *know* what a `struct ALMConfStr` consists of, or what an `IntelRecsPerPg` might be in that context.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however, my struct ALMConfStr is absolutely defined in the header before I try to compute clStructCount. Any other ideas?

Comment: From my header file:                                           typedef struct ALMConfStruct { uint8_t updateMode; uint8_t flashPgSize; uint8_t flashMaxPagesSize; uint8_t IntelRecsPerPg; fptr_t appResetAddr; uint16_t appEndAddr; uint8_t comIntf; }ALMConfStr;

Comment: Edit, sorry, nevermind, I was referencing the specific instance and not the struct type.

Comment: EDIT #2: Still not working (though now it compiles). I get a size of 1, when the value of IntelRecsPerPg is 8.

Comment: @nobby `IntelRecsPerPg` is a `uint8_t`, that's one byte, so a size of 1.

Comment: Because the example in the link I posted referenced an array, I thought this worked to take the value of the struct element. In fact, it takes the size of the member array. So what if my struct member is a uint8_t and I want to set an array size at runtime to equal the VALUE stored in the uint8_t?

Comment: Then you'd use `uint8_t clStructCount = conf->IntelRecsPerPg;` (ie, get the value rather than the size of the member), and then _declare an array of clStructCount elements_

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no definition of `struct ALMConfStr`

or `IntelRecsPerPg` is not a member of `struct ALMConfStr`

Say

```
struct ALMConfStr{
//some member variables
data_type IntelRecsPerPg;
//some more member variables
};
```

Basically `sizeof(((struct ALMConfStr *) 0)->IntelRecsPerPg)` tries to get the

```
sizeof(IntelRecsPerPg)
```

in the structure assuming that the structure is available at address 0.

Comment: Huh? Offset is not involved here.

Answer (score 0):

From a comment on Useless' answer:

> From my header file:

```
    typedef struct ALMConfStruct {
        uint8_t updateMode;
        uint8_t flashPgSize;
        uint8_t flashMaxPagesSize;
        uint8_t IntelRecsPerPg;
        fptr_t appResetAddr;
        uint16_t appEndAddr;
        uint8_t comIntf;
    }ALMConfStr;
```

Your `struct` tag is `ALMConfStruct` and not `ALMConfStr`, so

```
struct ALMConfStr
```

declares a new incomplete `struct` type. Remove the `struct`, or use `struct ALMConfStruct` in your code to determine the size.

```
uint8_t clStructCount = sizeof(((ALMConfStr *) 0)->IntelRecsPerPg);
```

or

```
uint8_t clStructCount = sizeof(((struct ALMConfStruct *) 0)->IntelRecsPerPg);
```