# Why cast 0 to a pointer can 'access'

Tags: c, pointers

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21386995/is-int-0-a-null-pointer), it is cleared say that (C99 definition 6.3.2.3p3 says)

> If a null pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a null pointer, is guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function.

But in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553296/c-sizeof-single-struct-member/3553321#3553321), @Joey Adams use the following macro:

```
#define member_size(type, member) sizeof(((type *)0)->member)
```

It seems that he use a **null pointer to access a member (an array in this case)** and he use this to know the size of a member. In the following assembly code(example from the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553296/c-sizeof-single-struct-member/3553321#3553321)), it has been already substitute by a number.

```
movl    $255, %esi   ---> printf("%lu",member_size(Parent, text));
movl    $.LC0, %edi
movl    $0, %eax
call    printf
```

So it seems that it has *'accessed' the member* and become the assembly code. But in the comment, he said 'it isn't actually dereferenced' and make me confused.

So my question:

- when is exactly the number calculated?
- why it can be accessed using a null pointer?

Comment: `sizeof` does not evaluate its operand (except in rare cases eg VLA)

Comment: @pmg I don't understand why VLA should be an exception to the rule that `sizeof` does not evaluate its operands. If `p` is a pointer to a VLA, then `sizeof *p` is determined **entirely on the base of its type** to be that size that **will have been previously evaluated at run-time** and stored somewhere safe for future reference. What would an example be of `sizeof` evaluating its operand?

Comment: @pmg But the member of the parent is a array, why it doesn't evaluate?

Comment: see [example at ideone](http://ideone.com/bSgLZX).

Comment: Oh, thanks. And sorry for duplicate.

Comment: @pmg Thanks. You may have found a bug in Frama-C (http://frama-c.com/ ).

Comment: @PascalCuoq: that was not my idea, but I'm happy to have unearthed a bug :)

Comment: @PascalCuoq also see [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21995718/1708801)