# Explaining sizeof(((rs_comm*)0)->ab[0]);

Tags: c++

At [xdn-project/digitalnote](https://github.com/xdn-project/digitalnote) `./src/crypto/crypto.cpp` file there is an error at line 338 when compiling (using cmake):

```
return sizeof(rs_comm) + pubs_count * sizeof(rs_comm().ab[0]);
                                                     ^
```

> error: value-initialization of incomplete type
>   ‘Crypto::rs_comm:: []’

I found the solution on [cryptonotefoundation/cryptonote](https://github.com/cryptonotefoundation/cryptonote/pull/42/files/692953fdc19dc2eef1b28ad21c851d2e9c30c6e8):

```
return sizeof(rs_comm) + pubs_count * sizeof(((rs_comm*)0)->ab[0]);
```

I can play with Java JDK quite well, but currently at C++ need help :) It would be nice to see detail explanation of this code part:

```
sizeof(((rs_comm*)0)->ab[0]);
```

My questions are:

1. Asterisk after `rs_comm` - what its for?
2. `0)` - what is the purpose of `0` here?

The fragment of code:

```
  struct rs_comm {
    Hash h;
    struct {
      EllipticCurvePoint a, b;
    } ab[];
  };

  static inline size_t rs_comm_size(size_t pubs_count) {
    return sizeof(rs_comm) + pubs_count * sizeof(rs_comm().ab[0]);
}
```

Comment: It's a horrible hack that invokes *undefined behavior*

Comment: Yes, I agree. But trying to figure it out.

Comment: Where is undefined behaviour?

Comment: It will return the size of the element of member `ab` of the struct `rs_common`.

Comment: @UnholySheep It is not undefined behavior, it will work on every major c compiler.

Comment: May be similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553296/c-sizeof-single-struct-member)

Comment: @UnholySheep it would be undefined behaviour in an evaluated context, but it's the operand to `sizeof`, so it matters less

Comment: Reading: [_Null Pointer Dereferencing Causes Undefined Behavior_](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2015/04/20/null-pointer-dereferencing-causes-undefined-behavior) by [Andrey Karpov](https://software.intel.com/en-us/user/308845) at software.intel.com/blogs, with an interesting exception just before the 'Acknowledgements' section. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[sizeof](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) is an operator that return the size of a specific type. It can work directly with a type or with an expression.

This part (rs_comm*)0 is taking 0 (0 is a valid null pointer constant) and casting it to a pointer of the struct rs_comm (or the class, I don't know the definition of rs_comm, but I am guessing).

Now, it is accessing using the -> operator to the data-member ab. ab has to be define as array, so it can get the first item in the array.

Because, sizeof doesn't really evaluate the expression but just figuring out the type and get the size of it.

So, the final result is the size of the first element in the array ab for the class/struct rs_comm.

Comment: Being pedantic, `0` is **not** a pointer value. But it is a valid *null pointer constant*, and thus will be converted to a *null pointer value* in a pointer context.

Comment: @Deduplicator be pedantic is useful with C++, thank, I have updated my answer

Comment: But according [this article](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2015/04/20/null-pointer-dereferencing-causes-undefined-behavior): _The pointer must be checked before being dereferenced_. Is this expression correct then: `sizeof(((rs_comm*)0)->ab[0])`? What is the simple way to check if `rs_comm` is `NULL` and if it is - return zero length, or if `rs_comm` was initialized - return the length of `ab[0]`?

Comment: @ErnestasGruodis please, read the link of the sizeof documentation, you will found: "When applied to an expression, sizeof does not evaluate the expression, and even if the expression designates a polymorphic object, the result is the size of the static type of the expression." So, you don't need to check against the null pointer because the expression is not evaluated.

Comment: So, even if `rs_comm` is not declared anywhere, the expression `sizeof(((rs_comm*)0)->ab[0])` will get the size of inner structure `ab[0]`? That is the size of `EllipticCurvePoint a` plus `EllipticCurvePoint b`?

Answer (score 1):

So `ab` is an member of struct `rs_comm`, and is an array.

If you have a *rs_comm object*, i.e. `rs_comm rs;`, but you don't know the type of `ab`, you want to know its size, `sizeof(rs.ab[0])` will do.

If you have *a pointer to rs_comm*, i.e. `rs_comm *p_rs;`, then `sizeof(p_rs->ab[0])` will do the same thing.

If you don't have a *rs_comm object* nor *a pointer to rs_comm*, you can change **a NULL pointer** to **a pointer to rs_comm**, this is what `((rs_comm *)0)` do.

Replace the `p_rs` in `sizeof(p_rs->ab[0])` with `((rs_comm *)0)`, you get `sizeof(((rs_comm *)0)->ab[0])`.

Answer (score 0):

sizeof(variable) .
return the size variable data type .
like 
char x ; 
cout << sizeof(x) ;
the result would be