# SUNPATHLEN on Linux. Where is it defined?

Tags: c, linux, sockets

Recently I begun to port some my TCP code from FreeBSD to Linux. Already had a bunch of questions ;) So, here is another one.

The C struct `sockaddr_un` on Linux have some different definition than of that on FreeBSD. But, to the question. I have such code in my project:

```
 }else if(AF_UNIX == domain){
  if(SUNPATHLEN == strnlen(a, SUNPATHLEN)){
   return -ENAMETOOLONG;
  }
```

The above tests that Maximum path should be no more than `SUNPATHLEN` constant. The `SUNPATHLEN` is defined on FreeBSD, but apparently not on Linux.

Looking through the `gcc -E source.c | grep -n4 sockaddr_un`, the struct definition is following:

```
1724:struct sockaddr_un
1725-  {
1726-    sa_family_t sun_family;
1727-    char sun_path[108];
1728-  };
```

Here the length of a buffer is explicitly set to be of `108`.

What is a general rule to check for buffer being trimmed/overflowed in Linux, for the case?

Comment: The question is fine, but I'm curious: what does this have to do with porting *TCP* code to Linux?  UNIX-domain sockets provide a stream-oriented mode, but it doesn't use TCP.

Comment: You could use the solutions to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3553296/3004881)

Comment: @JohnBollinger I want to use something like `socket_connect("tcp://127.0.0.1")` and `socket_connect("unix://tmp/unix_socket")`. I saw the approach with zeromq library.

Comment: @DanGetz Thank you, I think about define'ing `SUNPATHLEN` with the macro that you had suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Looking through the gcc -E source.c | grep -n4 sockaddr_un, the struct definition is following:

You don't have to (and shouldn't) trawl the source for this kind of information.  You should be looking at user-facing *documentation* to determine the interface characteristics on which you can rely.  In this case, you're looking for [**unix(7)**](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html):

> A UNIX domain socket address is represented in the following
> structure:
>
> ```
> struct sockaddr_un {
>     sa_family_t sun_family;               /* AF_UNIX */
>     char        sun_path[108];            /* Pathname */
> };
> ```
>
> The sun_family field always contains `AF_UNIX`.  **On Linux, sun_path is
> 108 bytes in size**

(emphasis added).

> What is a general rule to check for buffer being trimmed/overflowed in
> Linux, for the case?

No macro is defined for it, but the capacity of the path buffer is explicitly documented as 108 bytes.  You can (and probably should) define your own macro for this if you're going to perform tests related to it.

---

You could possibly do some variation on this to remove system dependencies:

```
static struct sockaddr_un dummy_sockaddr_un_;
#define MY_SUN_PATH_SIZE (sizeof(dummy_sockaddr_un_.sun_path))
```

Comment: I note further that [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/sys_un.h.html) does not specify the `SUNPATHLEN` macro or any other that conveys the size of the `sun_path` buffer.  It does observe that the size varies among known implementations, and that application programmers need to be aware and take that into account.